# How to calculate the displacement from the measured acceleration data?

Tags: matlab, integration

I have an acceleration data which is collected from a vehicle. I do also have a displacement measurement.

I would like to calcuate the displacement vector from the measured acceleration data, but no success yet.

Here is the data (the previous link was not working I updated the link):
https://ufile.io/zyw3r

[image: The measured acceleration data]

[image: The measured displacement data]
What I try:

```
filename = ('acc_time.csv'); 
accdata = csvread('acc_time.csv');

[mydata, myheader] = xlsread(filename); 
for i = 1:length(myheader)
      % compose a command to assign each column to a variable with the same 
      % name as the header
      commandExec = [myheader{i}, ' = ', 'mydata(:,', num2str(i) , ');'];
      % execute the composed command to actually create the variable
      evalin('base', commandExec ); 
end

vel_vector = cumtrapz(time,acc); 
disp_vector= cumtrapz(time,vel_vector);
plot(time, disp_vector)
```

and I get:
[image: Plot]

but the displacement vector should be squiggy not like linear incremental.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look linear to me. Looks like a quadratic function to me. Squiggliness is very likely lost (correctly so) due to the low-pass behaviour of integration.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right it is more like a quadratic behaviour. But It should look like as the acceleration signal. How should I integrate over acceleration signal?

Comment: No, it should not. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but I do also have displacement data of the same acceleration signal, and the displacement data I calculate via matlab and the measured displacement data are not the same.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz my velocity is a derivation with cumptraz. So it should not be taken into consideration. Only measured data is acceleration, I need to calculate the displacement from it, which should look like the acceleration data, should not have a linear trend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the observed effect occurs when there is an offset and/or linear drift present in your measured data. Double integration then leads to the quadratic (or higher order) effect observed in the data.

As @Stanley Pawlukiewicz states in his answer this can be due to the accelerometer registering gravity (not all accelerometers are capable of registering a constant acceleration field) but also due to temperature fluctuations, (electro)magnetic interference, strain at the base of the accelerometer, etc. Sometimes, it’s possible to “shield” your sensor for these effects but this can also be extremely challenging or expensive. In the latter case pre-processing your data can be an option too enable extracting meaningful results from your data.

The most straightforward approach to get rid of the quadratic drift in your double integrated acceleration signal is to detrend the data before integrating. If you substract the mean value before integrating the acceleration and velocity signals you should get reasonably “close” to the desired result (see matlab’s detrend function for other options).

Note that there also appears to be other noise and/or content in your measured acceleration signal; i.e. you will probably be able to get “close” to the desired result but will not get the exact same position signal. If that is critical you could use a more sophisticated signal processing approach or, if possible (and preferably) a better sensor (e.g. a position sensor).

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation! Actually I would like to learn more about the subject/affair of that gravity registration of accelerometers.

Comment: Google “MEMS accelerometer” or “DC response accelerometer” for a sensor type that can register gravity; google “ICP accelerometer” or “charge accelerometer” for (commonly used) sensor types that can not. Most manufacturers (e.g. PCB or Bruel&Kjaer) provide information on the working principles, common disturbance sources, calibration, etc. of their accelerometers. That should help you find what you’re searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have a similar problem, but I fixed by filtering the RAW acceleration data to remove noise, I use a fifth order butterworth filter and most of the problem was solved.